# SQL - Comparing difference between values in same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with how to compare values in the same column **LogNum** to find 'unusual' entries. For example, in my table below **LogTbl** we can see that on **ID** number 4 the **LogNum** entry jumps massively compared to the previous pattern of entries.

How can I compare these **LogNum** entries and identify/output any that have increased by say more than 5% from the previous entry, using **LogDate** to age the entries?

| ID | LogDate | LogNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2006-05-26 00:00:00.000 | 112 |
| 2 | 2006-07-19 00:00:00.000 | 145 |
| 3 | 2006-09-08 00:00:00.000 | 162 |
| 4 | 2006-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 1787 |

Thanks.

Comment: All your values are greater than 5% of the previous though?

Answer (score 0):

There is no formal criteria for your words 'masssive' and 'unusual'. However I suppose that you may try to select the records where LogNum will be within the borders `(LogNum >= MEAN(LogNum) - 2 * STDDEV(LogNum)) AND - LogNum <= MEAN(LogNum) + 2 * STDDEV(LogNum))`

Answer (score 0):

There's a wide interperetation of what your requirements are, one possible idea would be to identify a threshold using an average or standard deviation and filter rows that exceed the threshold.

```
with a as (
    select *, avg(lognum) over() threshold
  from t
)
select *
from a
where lognum > threshold
```

If you are interested in only differences between adjacent rows you could use `lead`, ie, find rows where the value is increases by >25% of the previous value

```
select Id, LogDate, Lognum
from (
    select *, Lead(lognum) over(order by logdate) nxt
    from t
)t
where nxt > lognum * 1.25
```